# Python: How to create new variable in each iteration of a for loop?

Tags: python

I need to create a long text string out of 3 lists.  This text string has to be in a very specific format where there's an element from each list separated by a space, and each group has a semicolon afterwards. The below script should run:

```
import math

reclassInt = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
minValueRange = [512, 550.0, 600.0, 650.0, 700.0, 750.0]
maxValueRange = [550.0, 600.0, 650.0, 700.0, 750.0, 755]

for numbers in reclassInt:
    newNums = numbers-1
    longString = str(minValueRange[newNums]) + " " + str(maxValueRange[newNums]) + " " + str(reclassInt[newNums]) + ";" 
    print longString
```

This will return 6 lines, the first being:

512 550.0 1;

Instead of printing these strings, I want to set a variable to each of them.  I want this variable to have a unique name for each iteration of the loop( based on reclassInt items).

Ideally this could create variables like line1, line2, ect to equal the string outputs from each iteration. Then I could string these together outside the loop to get my desired string.

To be clear my end goal is this exact string:

"512 550.0 1;550.0 600.0 2;600.0 650.0 3;650.0 700.0 4;700.0 750.0 5;750.0 755 6;"

Thanks All,...

Comment: dynamic naming is almost always a bad idea.  Usually it's much better to use a `dict`.  (also, your code could be cleaned up a bit by using `zip` :-)

Comment: What is that `bs` supposed to be doing there?

Comment: Looks like a `list` might be better here. I don't think the items really need to be named based on `reclassInt`; it looks like all that's really needed is that they be in order and accessible by index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
>>> d = {i+1:v for i,v in enumerate(zip(minValueRange, maxValueRange))}
>>> d
{1: (512, 550.0),
 2: (550.0, 600.0),
 3: (600.0, 650.0),
 4: (650.0, 700.0),
 5: (700.0, 750.0),
 6: (750.0, 755)}
```

Then to print your string:

```
>>> for k,v in d.iteritems():
...    print('{} {} {};'.format(v[0], v[1], k))
...
512 550.0 1;
550.0 600.0 2;
600.0 650.0 3;
650.0 700.0 4;
700.0 750.0 5;
750.0 755 6;
```

To get the string in one line, as per your update:

```
>>> ''.join('{} {} {};'.format(v[0], v[1], k) for k,v in d.iteritems())
'512 550.0 1;550.0 600.0 2;600.0 650.0 3;650.0 700.0 4;700.0 750.0 5;750.0 755 6;'
```

Also if that's your only requirement you don't need to generate the dictionary and can combine everything into this:

```
>>> ''.join('{} {} {};'.format(v[0], v[1], k+1) for k,v in enumerate(zip(minValueRange, maxValueRange)))
'512 550.0 1;550.0 600.0 2;600.0 650.0 3;650.0 700.0 4;700.0 750.0 5;750.0 755 6;'
```

Comment: I added to the original question showing the exact syntax I need.  I did not get this to work.  Thanks...

Comment: Thanks- your 1 line does it all.

Answer (score 2):

To make things much simpler, and better, you can use a dictionary:

```
longStrings= {}
for numbers in reclassInt:
    newNums = numbers-1
    d["longString_%d"%numbers] = str(minValueRange[newNums]) + " " + str(maxValueRange[newNums]) + " " + str(reclassInt[newNums]) + ";" 
    bs = "ls" + str(numbers)
```

Comment: I tried this but when I added the command to print longStrings and it was still empty- {}